# check if value exists in multidimensional array

Tags: php, html

I want to make my category menu responsive to the projects displayed.
The projects have multiple categories so multiple category-menu-links can be active.
Whichever category the project belongs to is specified on an included php file in an multidimensional array…

e.g.

```
$allProjects = array(
    'project1' => array('corporate'),
    'project2' => array('corporate', 'print'),
    'project3' => array('web')
);
```

Now I want to check for each category if it is a value of the array 'project1', 'project2', 'project3',… within the array $allProjects and if so echo 'active'.

So far I have…

```
<?php if (($_GET['cat'] == 'corporate')) {echo 'active';}; || if (isset ($_GET['project'])) {if in_array('corporate', $_GET['project']) {echo 'active';}; ?>
```

Does that make sense?

UPDATE:

What I need is to check in the multidimensional array at a specific key (2nd level array) if a value exists (3rd level array)

so I guess something like this…

```
$project = $_GET('project');
$category = $_GET('cat');

foreach ($allProjects as $project => $categories) {
if in_array($category, $project);
echo 'yes';
}
```

I use $project, variables defined above, as key but that doesn't work. It expects the parameters to be arrays. All I want is to use the name of the project (defined in $project) as a key for the in_array function and check for appearance of $category in the values.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_search()` to search for a specific value in your array. This function returns the key corresponding to the value if found, `false` otherwise.

So what you will want to do is loop each subarray:

```
$category = $_GET['cat'];
$allProjects = array(
    'project1' => array('corporate'),
    'project2' => array('corporate', 'print'),
    'project3' => array('web')
);

foreach ($allProjects as $projectName => $categories) {
    $categoryIndex = array_search($category, $categories);
    if ($categoryIndex !== false) {
        echo 'active: ' . $categoryIndex;
        // Do something with $categoryIndex and $projectName here
    }
}
```

**Update**:

Looks like this is your answer:

```
$project = $_GET('project');
$category = $_GET('cat');

if (isset($allProjects[$project]) && in_array($category, $allProjects[$project])) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me an invalid argument: <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @tgifred Make sure $allProjects is initialized correctly like shown in your question. Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks RuubW, I tried, I think I didn't make myself clear. I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, what is in $_GET['project'] in your condition, but this will at least make your code better readable. :)

```
isActive = false;
foreach($allProjects as $project) {
  if(in_array($_GET['cat'], $project) isActive = true;
}
```

Comment: you should add a break to finish the cycle after first match. there's no need to continue the loop

Answer (score 1):

You perhaps want to go through the array using a foreach and set your active  / non active indicator accordingly.